# HTTP POST request always fails

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to construct an HTTP POST request to my server but it continues to fail. I made the same response in Postman and the request succeeded but it fails when reconstructed in Angular 5:

```
// https://my-url/api/users/:id/ban
const banUrl = `users/${id}/ban/`;
let params = this.getBanParams('short');

return this.httpClient.post(banUrl, {'ban_type': 'SHORT'});
```

My understanding of the above is that it will place the `ban_type` parameter in the `body` of the request for the server to consume but I keep getting a `404` error back from the server. I believe that the server is looking at the body for the `ban_type` but it can't find it in whatever format it's expecting.

I've also tried it like this:

```
const banUrl = `users/${id}/ban/`;
let params = new HttpParams()
  .set('ban_type', 'SHORT');

return this.httpClient.post(banUrl, params);
```

but keep getting the same `404` error. How should I restructure this?

Thanks

P.S. I do have an `api-interceptor` in place which appends the necessary `HEADERS` and points the request at the correct place but these `HEADERS` do appear to correctly get added as I can see them in the request preview:

[image]

Comment: 404 is not found.... `https://my-url/api/users/:id/ban` does not match `users/${id}/ban/`

Comment: Is it 401 or 404 that you get ?

Comment: And 401 means that you're not authenticated. Start by deciding which error you actually get. Then look at the request body (and at the documentation of HttpClient): it will send the object as a JSON body, not as a form parameter. But none of the error codes (401 or 404) are linked to that anyway.

Comment: Sorry my mistake - its a 404 error - plus @epascarello i swapped that out with my-url for privacy and already mentioned that the interceptor points it to the right place

Comment: 404 is saying the page does not exist..... so are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: @epascarello the path is 100% correct. I'm considering closing this now as it worked but the API call only works for certain users suggesting the problem is on the server side

Comment: You may want to look into CORS settings on your backend, that could be causing the 404 error.